# helm M-x is executing command twice?

Tags: helm

I execute a command `M-x pyvenv-workon`

It is called twice as below, wonder why

The first call stack trace shows the correct path to the virtualenv

```
  spacemacs//python-setup-shell("/Users/littlehome/virtualenvs/can")
  funcall(spacemacs//python-setup-shell "/Users/littlehome/virtualenvs/can")
  spacemacs/python-setup-everything("/Users/littlehome/virtualenvs/can")
  apply(spacemacs/python-setup-everything "/Users/littlehome/virtualenvs/can")
  pyvenv-activate("/Users/littlehome/virtualenvs/can")
  apply(#f(compiled-function (name) "Activate a virtual environment from $WORKON_HOME.\n\nIf the virtual environment NAME is already active, this function\ndoes not try to reactivate the environment." (interactive #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x12a7cc692c045eca>)) #<bytecode 0xdc7dd672f6e05f>) "can")
  pyvenv-workon("can")
  funcall-interactively(pyvenv-workon "can")
  call-interactively(pyvenv-workon record nil)
  command-execute(pyvenv-workon record)
  helm-M-x-execute-command(pyvenv-workon)
  helm-execute-selection-action-1()
  helm-execute-selection-action()
  helm-internal
  apply
  helm
  apply
  helm
  helm-M-x-read-extended-command
  helm-M-x(nil)
  funcall-interactively(helm-M-x nil)
  call-interactively(helm-M-x)
  (let ((completion-styles completion-styles)) (add-to-list 'completion-styles 'flex t) (call-interactively 'helm-M-x))
  spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching()
  funcall-interactively(spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching)
  call-interactively(spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching nil nil)
  command-execute(spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching)
```

Whereas 2nd call (which is called automatically, and I don't know why it's getting called) doesn't have the correct path

```
  spacemacs//python-setup-shell("can")
  funcall(spacemacs//python-setup-shell "can")
  spacemacs/python-setup-everything("can")
  apply(spacemacs/python-setup-everything "can")
  pyvenv-workon("can")
  funcall-interactively(pyvenv-workon "can")
  call-interactively(pyvenv-workon record nil)
  command-execute(pyvenv-workon record)
  helm-M-x-execute-command(pyvenv-workon)
  helm-execute-selection-action-1()
  helm-execute-selection-action()
  helm-internal
  apply
  helm
  apply
  helm
  helm-M-x-read-extended-command
  helm-M-x(nil)
  funcall-interactively(helm-M-x nil)
  call-interactively(helm-M-x)
  (let ((completion-styles completion-styles)) (add-to-list 'completion-styles 'flex t) (call-interactively 'helm-M-x))
  spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching()
  funcall-interactively(spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching)
  call-interactively(spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching nil nil)
  command-execute(spacemacs/helm-M-x-fuzzy-matching)
```

--

- edit

Turns out pyvenv-workon has 2 same defadvice attached to it.